# Oracle Shrink Space

Tags: oracle

What happens when the process is interrupted in between the shrink space process.
E.g.
I am having a loop of 10 tables and each iteration is shrinking space of the table. When the process is doing for 5th table, it is interrupted by the user and operation is cancelled. What will happen to the previous 4 table and 5th table. Will the space be shrinked or we need to re-run the process.

Comment: A space shrink is a physical operation -- DDL, if you will.  The 'previous four' tables that completed the shrink .... completed the shrink.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @edStevens. Should i run the gather stats to make the DB consistent.

Comment: If the database is open, then it is 'consistent'.  (The term "consistent" has a very precise meaning in the oracle world).  It should not be necessary to run stats, as oracle has a built-in stats job that runs every evening.  The view DBA_TABLES will tell you when the table was last analyzed.  I leave it as an exercise for the student to check the docs for details.